# What is minimum transportation cost by Vam method?

Tags: operations-research

[image]
According to table in image (at the bottom)
If an arrival of VVIP blocks the traffic from branch I to customer C and D and from II to customer D and E. What is minimum transpotation cost by vam method.
My textbook answer is 221. But I am not getting it. Please help me

Comment: You should show the work you did and the answer you got so that we may be able to see where you encountered difficulty. Also, the extraneous table at the top of the photo makes this question confusing even with the explanation, and even if it were cropped better we like to avoid showing photographs of formulas and tables when it can be avoided. You can format a copy of the table using advice here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: I get 229km for VAM assuming 0 penalty costs for unused trucks. Note that the VAM does not necessarily give the minimal solution.

Comment: I got 221. If you edit the question to show your work (that is, show each step you took), I could indicate where we differ. It is a lot of work to type in all those details, I understand, but can you understand why it makes more sense for you to do that than for me to do it?

Comment: Pls upload ur working .i will match my working with urs. Thnks.

Comment: @David K, I get 229 for VAM then 221 after stepping stone (minimal solution).

Comment: @Paul I suppose it's possible I overlooked a row or column I was _supposed_ to work on next according to the method and by dumb luck this mistake led to the optimal answer. I just learned the method in order to work on this question. But until someone writes it up step by step (and I still think OP should be the one to do it), we have no way to check for such errors.

Comment: @David K - the OP definitely should!